# Adding values to all rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I have two pandas dataframes ***df1*** (of length 2) and ***df2*** (of length about 30 rows). Index values of df1 are always different and never occur in df2. I would like to add the average of columns from ***df1***  to corresponding columns of ***df2***. Example: add 0.6 to all rows of c1 and 0.9 to all rows of c2 etc ...

```
df1: 
  Date       c1   c2   c3   c4    c5   c6 ...  c10
2017-09-10  0.5  0.6  1.2   0.7  1.3  1.8 ...  1.3
2017-09-11  0.7  1.2  1.3   0.4  0.7  0.4 ...  1.5


df2:
  Date       c1   c2   c3   c4    c5   c6 ...  c10
2017-09-12  0.9  0.1  1.4   0.9  1.5  1.9 ...  1.9
2017-09-13  0.2  1.8  1.2   1.4  2.7  0.8 ...  1.1
    :                                  :  
    :                                  :     
2017-10-10  1.5  0.9  1.5   0.9  1.6  1.8 ...  1.7
2017-10-11  2.7  1.1  1.9   0.4  0.8  0.8 ...  1.3
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: What is index value of appended row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `mean` on `df1`, it calculates over each column by default and produces a `pd.Series`.

When adding adding a `pd.Series` to a `pd.DataFrame` it aligns the index of the `pd.Series` with the columns of the `pd.DataFrame` and broadcasts along the index of the `pd.DataFrame`... by default.

The only tricky bit is handling the `Date` column.

**Option 1**

```
m = df1.mean()
df2.loc[:, m.index] += m

df2

         Date   c1   c2    c3    c4   c5   c6  c10
0  2017-09-12  1.5  1.0  2.65  1.45  2.5  3.0  3.3
1  2017-09-13  0.8  2.7  2.45  1.95  3.7  1.9  2.5
2  2017-10-10  2.1  1.8  2.75  1.45  2.6  2.9  3.1
3  2017-10-11  3.3  2.0  3.15  0.95  1.8  1.9  2.7
```

If I know that `'Date'` is always in the first column, I can:

```
df2.iloc[:, 1:] += df1.mean()
df2

         Date   c1   c2    c3    c4   c5   c6  c10
0  2017-09-12  1.5  1.0  2.65  1.45  2.5  3.0  3.3
1  2017-09-13  0.8  2.7  2.45  1.95  3.7  1.9  2.5
2  2017-10-10  2.1  1.8  2.75  1.45  2.6  2.9  3.1
3  2017-10-11  3.3  2.0  3.15  0.95  1.8  1.9  2.7
```

---

**Option 2**
Notice that I use the `append=True` parameter in the `set_index` just incase there are things in the index you don't want to mess up.

```
df2.set_index('Date', append=True).add(df1.mean()).reset_index('Date')

         Date   c1   c2    c3    c4   c5   c6  c10
0  2017-09-12  1.5  1.0  2.65  1.45  2.5  3.0  3.3
1  2017-09-13  0.8  2.7  2.45  1.95  3.7  1.9  2.5
2  2017-10-10  2.1  1.8  2.75  1.45  2.6  2.9  3.1
3  2017-10-11  3.3  2.0  3.15  0.95  1.8  1.9  2.7
```

If you don't care about the index, you can shorten this to

```
df2.set_index('Date').add(df1.mean()).reset_index()

         Date   c1   c2    c3    c4   c5   c6  c10
0  2017-09-12  1.5  1.0  2.65  1.45  2.5  3.0  3.3
1  2017-09-13  0.8  2.7  2.45  1.95  3.7  1.9  2.5
2  2017-10-10  2.1  1.8  2.75  1.45  2.6  2.9  3.1
3  2017-10-11  3.3  2.0  3.15  0.95  1.8  1.9  2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

If all columns are in both data frames, then just

```
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[col] = df2[col] + df1[col].mean()
```

if the columns are not necessarily in both then:

```
for col in df2.columns:
    if col in df1.columns:
        df2[col] = df2[col] + df1[col].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more efficient way but here is a quick and dirty solution. I hope this helps!

```
d = {'c1': [0.5,0.7], 'c2': [0.6,1.2],'c3': [1.2,1.3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['2017-09-10','2017-09-11'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=['2017-09-12','2017-09-13'])
```

df1

```
      Date   c1 c2  c3
2017-09-10  0.5 0.6 1.2
2017-09-11  0.7 1.2 1.3
```

df2

```
Date   c1   c2  c3
2017-09-12  0.5 0.6 1.2
2017-09-13  0.7 1.2 1.3
```

The averages of each column in df1 can be obtained using the describe() function

```
df1.describe().ix['mean']

c1    0.60
c2    0.90
c3    1.25
```

And now, simply add the series to df2

```
df2 + df1.describe().ix['mean']

Date     c1 c2  c3
2017-09-12  1.1 1.5 2.45
2017-09-13  1.3 2.1 2.55
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way of doing it , just simplified this a little bit

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
date_today=datetime.now()

#Creating df1 & df2 
df1=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date':[date_today,date_today],
        'c1':[0.5,0.4],
        'c2':[0.6,0.3]
    }
)
df2=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Date':[date_today,date_today,date_today],
        'c1':[0.9,0.7,0.6],
        'c2':[0.8,0.4,0.3]
    }
)


#getting average of column c1
avg=df1["c1"].mean()

#Adding the average to your existing column of df2
df2['c1']+avg
```