# How to add the values of one smaller DataFrame to part of another mixed type DataFrame, but only to rows after some arbitrary row index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two .csv files, one contains what could be described as a header and a body. The header contains data like the total number of rows, datetime, what application generated the data, and what line the body starts on. The second file contains a single row.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=list('abcdef'))
>>> df
                 a           b    c    d    e    f
0   data start row           5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1        row count           7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2          made by     foo.exe  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3             date  01-01-2000  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4                a           b    c    d    e    f
5              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
6              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
7              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
8              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
9              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
10             0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
11             0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("extra_data.csv")
>>> df2
     a    b    c
0  6.0  5.0  4.0
>>> row = df2.loc[0]
>>>
```

I am having trouble modifying the 'a', 'b' and 'c' columns and then saving the DataFrame to a new .csv file.

I have tried adding the row by way of slicing and the addition operator but this did not work:

```
>>> df[5:,'a':'c'] += row

TypeError: '(slice(5, None, None), slice('a', 'c', None))' is an invalid key
>>>
```

I also tried the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967921/14041661), but this gave a similar error:

```
>>> df[5:,row.index] += row

TypeError: '(slice(5, None, None), Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object'))' is an invalid key
>>>
```

I suspect the problem is coming from object dtypes so I tried converting a subframe to the float type:

```
>>> sub_section = df.loc[5:,['a','b','c']].astype(float)
>>> sub_section
      a    b    c
5   0.0  1.0  2.0
6   0.0  1.0  2.0
7   0.0  1.0  2.0
8   0.0  1.0  2.0
9   0.0  1.0  2.0
10  0.0  1.0  2.0
11  0.0  1.0  2.0
>>> sub_section += row
>>> sub_section
      a    b    c
5   6.0  6.0  6.0
6   6.0  6.0  6.0
7   6.0  6.0  6.0
8   6.0  6.0  6.0
9   6.0  6.0  6.0
10  6.0  6.0  6.0
11  6.0  6.0  6.0
>>> df
                 a           b    c    d    e    f
0   data start row           5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1        row count           7  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2          made by     foo.exe  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3             date  01-01-2000  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4                a           b    c    d    e    f
5              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
6              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
7              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
8              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
9              0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
10             0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
11             0.0         1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
>>>
```

Obviously, in this case df.loc[] is returning a copy, and then modifying the copy does nothing to the df.

How do I modify parts of a DataFrame (dtype=object) and then save the changes?

Comment: What is the purpose of that header data? In pandas it will only complicate your life by forcing the dtype to be upcast to `object` and it requires a lot of additional slicing. A better option would be to read only the data (you can store the "header" in a separate frame) and then when you go to export write the header, then write the data in `append` mode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829923/write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-txt-file/51829985#51829985

Comment: The header has no value at this stage but is used in further down-stream processing. I will attempt to do what you have recommended though.

Comment: @ALollz this was the correct path to take, thanks for the help!